# what is the best practice for app documentation?

Tags: documentation, refactoring, data-modeling, software-design

Having worked for a couple of years in software development, I grew wondering how to effectively communicate at work as of nitty gritty details of UX, functionality changes, error reporting system, and so on.

I have worked for two small companies here in South Korea and found out communication is done only orally from the start to the end, and never had any habit of software documentation.

I think it’s very odd because meticulous planning and effective software management cannot be done with spoken communication only.
(Although, I think in some sense, it may be justified if a company is not big enough to handle the extra workload.)

So, recently, I am genuinely interested in written communication for software, trying to rekindle a little bit knowledge of software engineering that I learned at college.

I’m trying to teach myself how to visualise my work and practice documentation on my own in practical level.

So, my question would be

1. Do you know any free graphic tools that can help me draw diagrams or UML, or etc?
2. Also, It will be appreciated if you could talk about how you document your app for future refactoring and better management.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2. Also, It will be appreciated if you could talk about how you document your app for future refactoring and better management.

I think you need to read about Agile software development.
[Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org/)

Make attention on the next point:

> Working software over comprehensive documentation

In your situation this can be explained as software writed in "clean" and understandable way with suits of unit and acceptance tests will be more effective then writing static documentation and UML diagrams.

I found UML diagrams are good for designing components in the beginning(but usually had used white boards). Then all diagrams was thrown away after all needed unit, acceptance tests was created.

Regular code reviews are good dynamic tool for sharing best practices, code styles or other information about developing software. So while you sharing knowledge about your software between members regularly, information will stay up-to-date inside team.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll look into those you mentioned.